# Prove : $\frac{x}{y}=\frac{ad+bc}{ab+cd}$

Tags: geometry

The quadrilateral $ABCD$ is cyclic $(O)$; $AB=a, BC=b, CD=c, AD=d, AC=x, BD=y$.

> Prove : $\frac{x}{y}=\frac{ad+bc}{ab+cd}$

Thanks :)

P/s : I have no ideas about this problem ! :(

Comment: May be you wanted to write $CD=c$?

Comment: @kmitov : Yes, I'm sorry !

Answer (score 1):

$S_{ABC}=\frac{1}{2}ab\sin B$,     Sine theorem says that $\frac{x}{2R}=\sin B$

$S_{ABC}=\frac{1}{2}ab\frac{x}{2R}$

The same for 
$S_{ADC}=\frac{1}{2}cd \sin D$,  where $\sin D=\sin (\pi - B) = \sin B = \frac{x}{2R}.$

Now you have $S_{ABCD}=\frac{x}{4R}(ab+cd)$

From the other two trinagles you have

$S_{ABCD}=\frac{y}{4R}(ad+cb)$

Therfore $\frac{x}{4R}(ab+cd) = \frac{y}{4R}(ad+cb)$